# How to set table header to fixed while scrolling without a thead generated by GridView

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following table which has the first row as header:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>check1</th>
        <th>check2</th>
        <th>check3</th>
        <th>check4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <!--...-->
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njde3c8a/

It doesn't have any `thead` but how can I make the header stick when scrolling.

Here is what I have with @mtwallet's answer:

[image]

[image]

I had to set the `fixedHeader` width to `98.2%` to ensure it didn't overlap the scrollbar. I would like to make the width similar to the rows in the `tbody` as close to as possible. Is there any way to get it by percentage rather than pixel?

`GridView`:

```
<asp:Table ID="ResultsTable" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Visible="false" Width="70%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell width="100%">
            <div id="GridPanel" style="height:350px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;">
                <div>
            <%--<asp:Panel ID="GridPanel" Width="100%" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="300px">--%>
                 <asp:GridView ID="BookingResults" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"> <%--OnRowCommand="BookingResults_RowCommand"--%> 
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="commHdr" Text="Show Guideline" CssClass="sg" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnShow3" CssClass="btnSearch3" Text="VIEW" OnClientClick="javascript:test(this);return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic" HeaderText="Topic" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-CssClass="tTitle"  />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Specialty" HeaderText="Specialty" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Provider Name">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                  <div id="dvHide" class="clsHide">
                                       <asp:Label ID="lblEllipsis" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Provider") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Provider") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                              </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-CssClass="sumM">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Guideline" HeaderText="Guideline" ItemStyle-CssClass="gLine" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gLine" />
                    </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--</asp:Panel>--%>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: Do you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/fhff4w3u/?

Comment: Almost, except what if the table was not at the top of the page?

Comment: Can you show some more HTML to give an idea how your page is laid out?

Comment: I added a fiddle to show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's HTML (in part)

```
<table id="ResultsTable">
<tr>
    <td style="width:100%;"><div id="GridPanel" style="height:300px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;">

    <table id="ctl00_ctl33_g_bae61ba3_d1d6_49b5_8dca_f2de96b61f3d_gridHeader"></table>

     <div>
         <table id="BookingResults">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <span id="commHdr" class="sg">Show Guideline</span>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">Topic</th>
                    <th scope="col">Location</th>
                    <th scope="col">Specialty</th>
                    <th scope="col">Provider Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Summary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a onclick="javascript:test(this);return false;" id="btnShow3" class="btnSearch3" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl33$g_bae61ba3_d1d6_49b5_8dca_f2de96b61f3d$BookingResults$ctl02$btnShow3&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">VIEW</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tTitle" valign="top">
                        topic
                    </td>
```

JS

```
//Get the first tr
var firstRow = $('.header');

//Clone the first row
firstRow.clone().attr('class','fixedHeader').prependTo('#ResultsTable');

//Match the th widths of the cloned tr
//This can be done with just css if you like
firstRow.find('th').each(function(i) {
    var thWidth = $(this).width();

    $('.fixedHeader th').eq(i).css({
        width: thWidth   
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#ResultsTable {
    position: relative;
}

.fixedHeader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    background: white; 
}
```

JSFiddle

Here is a link to the full solution and original markup http://jsfiddle.net/mt89bevk/45/

Comment: I tried editing this one: http://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/3262/. But how can I add the first row in the header?

Comment: I amended the answer and also the fiddle. I hope this helps.

Comment: Please add the fiddle link :) Thanks.

Comment: This is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/gxxn9bkt/ < this code is what the full generated page looks like. I added a scrollbar in the outer DIV but now trying to make the header stick on DIV scroll. If I can just do it on the table itself, I can remove all the extra divs and table.

Comment: I added a link to my answer above

Comment: Wow... awesome! I will implement it in my GridView code in my ASP.net page and update you. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question with a representation of your markup so others can understand what we have done. You can accept the answer if you like :)

Comment: Just added the link for the final solution / markup

Comment: for some reason the TH are not matching up. I updated my question with some screenshot. I am requesting help one last time :). The jsfiddle doesn't line up correctly either :(

Comment: I opened a new question if it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412593/how-to-match-the-width-of-a-cloned-th-with-that-of-the-table-cell

Comment: Is this styling auto-generated by your .NET framework? or can I change this markup to achieve the same look? I just want to know if I am stuck with what I see on the fiddle.

Comment: It is auto generated by .NET. I will post the GridView code in my question. lol @ stuck with... yes... me too! ;)

Comment: When I highlight the cloned header, it looks like there are space left toward the right. Now that I think about it, originally the GridView generates an extra column which I hide from view during runtime. Is that why? Can we clone every column except the last one and I think that will fix the issue. I added an `alert` and it said there are 6 columns starting with 0, which means we have to take into account only 5 columns and hide the last column in the clone TR.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/rfwjcoq5/21/ you had set the table width to 96%

Comment: Where is the 96%? Weird, i don't see it in the fiddle :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rfwjcoq5/22/ If you stretch the window the header doesn't match the table body :/ I tried adding the same code in `resize`: http://jsfiddle.net/rfwjcoq5/23/ but that didn't work.

Comment: I removed the 96% from the fiddle. The script possibly needs to put in a window resize handler too.

Comment: The second fiddle has the resize but it doesn't do it :/